# Disable a gitlab-runner for a project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a private gitlab group which has two runners configured.

One runner runs anything on that group and the second one just picks jobs with tag long-running.

Below is the simplest gitlab ci file

```
stages:
  - build
sample:
  stage: build
  image: alpine:latest
  tags:
    - long-running
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - echo "task executed."
```

Is there a way I can make the first one skip this job completely?

I know that I can disable the runner for this project alone but that would mean I have to manually enable the runner for all the 100+ projects in the group.

Does the specific runner have a priority? I would be pretty much happy with that :)

Or is there a workaround to make sure that the second alone picks the jobs with that tag. Searched a little but didn't find any simpler explanation. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find much help on this. But however, we have followed a workaround.
We created a new runner specific to that project.

Then we have set `concurrent = 2` found at `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`. We are now able to have 2 concurrent non-blocking runners. However, I know that this is not the optimal solution. Still looking for ways to block a runner from picking jobs with tags.
Hope this helps.

Comment: hello there. did you find a solution for this? I have a runner that fails my jobs and don't have access to settings to disable it for the specific 2 projects, but I was looking for a way to disable that specific runner from the `.gitlab-ci` file within my code.

Comment: @senaps We have moved from the solution which I mentioned above. We have moved to a different job runner for this case. I still think [Specific Runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/runners_scope.html#specific-runners) would fit the case.